# dockerfile: dlerror:libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file

Tags: dockerfile

trying to build my first dockerfile for vision transformer on ubuntu 20.04. ran into

> 2022-11-04 09:08:49.205922: W external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64]
> Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror:
> libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
> /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64

it stopped at git clone (since this is the last step appeared in the terminal before the error):

> Step 7/11 : RUN git clone
> https://github.com/google-research/vision_transformer.git     &&cd
> vision_transformer     && pip3 install pip --upgrade     && pip
> install -r vit_jax/requirements.txt     &&python -m vit_jax.main
> --workdir=/tmp/vit-$(date +%s)     --config=$(pwd)/vit_jax/configs/vit.py:b16,cifar10     --config.pretrained_dir='gs://vit_models/imagenet21k'     && pip cache purge

below is my dockerfile:

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.8.1-cuda10.2-cudnn7-runtime

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ARG USERNAME=user
WORKDIR /dockertest
ARG WORKDIR=/dockertest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        automake autoconf libpng-dev nano python3-pip \
        sudo curl zip unzip libtool swig zlib1g-dev pkg-config \
        python3-mock libpython3-dev libpython3-all-dev \
        g++ gcc cmake make pciutils cpio gosu wget \
        libgtk-3-dev libxtst-dev sudo apt-transport-https \
        build-essential gnupg git xz-utils vim libgtk2.0-0 libcanberra-gtk-module\
        # libva-drm2 libva-x11-2 vainfo libva-wayland2 libva-glx2 \
        libva-dev libdrm-dev xorg xorg-dev protobuf-compiler \
        openbox libx11-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev \
        libtbb2 libtbb-dev libopenblas-dev libopenmpi-dev \
    && sed -i 's/# set linenumbers/set linenumbers/g' /etc/nanorc \
    && apt clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN git clone https://github.com/google-research/vision_transformer.git \
    &&cd vision_transformer \
    && pip3 install pip --upgrade \
    && pip install -r vit_jax/requirements.txt \
    &&python -m vit_jax.main --workdir=/tmp/vit-$(date +%s) \
    --config=$(pwd)/vit_jax/configs/vit.py:b16,cifar10 \
    --config.pretrained_dir='gs://vit_models/imagenet21k' \
    && pip cache purge

RUN echo "root:root" | chpasswd \
    && adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" "${USERNAME}" \
    && echo "${USERNAME}:${USERNAME}" | chpasswd \
    && echo "%${USERNAME}    ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD:    ALL" >> /etc/sudoers.d/${USERNAME} \
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/${USERNAME}
USER ${USERNAME}
RUN sudo chown -R ${USERNAME}:${USERNAME} ${WORKDIR}
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}
```

Comment: A clue as to which step this is occurring at, might be useful.

Comment: @SiHa i update the question to the earliest error i could find while running it. but i have no clue which step it is occurring at.

Comment: What do you mean you have no clue? The steps are output to the console as it builds `Step 1/10 : FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.8.1-cuda10.2-cudnn7-runtime` etc...

Comment: @SiHa i updated the question and added the last step i saw in the terminal. it stopped at git clone, so i think it indicates the problem occurs when trying to setup vit.

Comment: Try separating those commands into individual `RUN` lines (use `WORKDIR` instead of `cd` though)

Comment: @Phil nope that does not work, error same as before

Comment: I didn't say it would solve anything but it would help you narrow down exactly which command is failing

Comment: @Phil welp it doesn't help this time, but thanks for the tip for my future debugging.